Interpreting different versions of the aggregate demand and supply model
In Ben Bernanke's Macroeconomics, he explains the two major approaches to business cycle analysis in terms of the IS-LM & AD-AS model.
The Keynesian SRAS curve can be represented as a flat line — firms are willing to supply the demanded quantity at the going price with prices being fixed in the short run.

The classical model with misperceptions, can be represented by this diagram:

However, when I was on khanacademy, I found this diagram:

This doesn't seem consistent with either of the two approaches.. I'm confused. On top of that there's these different "zones" like the keynesian zones etc. What is going on here and how is this to be interpreted in terms of the different approaches to analysing business cycles?
